# How can i make my exe to be bounded to some other exe?

Tags: c#

How can i make my exe to be bounded to some other exe?
I mean that,
For Ex- my application is - A.
and one another application is also running independently B.
Now how can i make my application to be closed when application B is closed?

Comment: You can periodically check if the app is running and if not, terminate it.

Comment: A continuous timer kind of stuff? Won't it a more heavy?

Comment: Perhaps a `Mutex` with infinite timeout, as it doesn't require polling?

Comment: static void _Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsProcessRunningInThisSession(_BoundProcessExeName))
            {
                _Timer.Enabled = false;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(900);
                Application.Exit();
            }
        } this helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a running method in your Main, that searches for application B's process.
And if not found `Application.exit()` 
Thats keeping it simple...

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify application B, use the `Process` class, and its `CloseMainWindow` method. See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx).

If you cannot modify application B, you'll have to poll for it in application A. Again, use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Comment: No. I can't. it can be any thing.